# Value transformation in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

I'm working with a table of data as following:

```
User ID:       Event name:
111            Event 1
222            Event 2
333            Event 3
111            Event 4
444            Event 5
111            Event 6
```

So, what I'm trying to achieve is get a report in another sheet, which would

a) correspond user ID: 111, 222, 333, 444 with user names: name 1, name 2, etc.
 
b) count the total number of events per each user. Any idea how this can be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

- create a sheet where you assign IDs to names
- use this simple query formula:

  ```
  =ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY({IFERROR(VLOOKUP(Sheet1!A1:A, Sheet2!A1:B, 2, 0)), Sheet1!B1:B}, 
   "select Col1, count(Col1) 
    where Col2 contains 'event' 
    group by Col1 
    label Col1'Name', count(Col1)'Events count'"))
  ```

[image: 0]

- **[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/18Dj1Y2yPoKnmPhyWiTgVUZylaRfSW8LSdCBfBwDIW0o/edit#gid=2000446830)**